# Imagick `convert` works only in terminal and not in PHP

Tags: php, osx-lion, mamp, imagick

### ACTUAL SITUATION

MacBook Pro early 2008

OSX Lion 10.7.3

MAMP 2.0.5

ImageMagick-x86_64-apple-darwin11.3.0.tar.gz - installed and perfectly working from Terminal

gplgs-8.71.dmg - installed and perfectly working from Terminal and Imagick

### WHAT WORKS?

Using terminal the "convert" command works perfectly! I can convert PDF in JPG without any problem...

### WHAT IS THE PROBLEM?

If I try to use Imagick in PHP lunching the (simplest) demo command:

*"convert logo: logo.gif"*

Nothing happens! I followed [this guide](http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2010/05/11/imagemagick-with-mamp/) step by step and I know that I've to modify the "envvars" file and I made it but... it is not the solution!

I tried to read shell errors but nothing is returned in PHP... I tried all kind of commands:

```
define('MAGICK_PATH', '/Applications/MAMP/bin/ImageMagick/ImageMagick-6.7.5/bin/');

echo exec(MAGICK_PATH.'convert logo: logo.gif', $output);
var_dump($output);
=> array(0) { }


$output = shell_exec(MAGICK_PATH."convert logo: logo.gif");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
=> *nothing*


$last_line = system(MAGICK_PATH.'convert logo: logo.gif', $retval);
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
=> Last line of the output:
=> Return value: 5


$last_line = system(MAGICK_PATH.'convert -version', $retval);
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
=> Last line of the output:
=> Return value: 5


$last_line = system(MAGICK_PATH."convert -colorspace RGB -interlace none -density 104.6x104.6 -quality 100 -bordercolor white doc.pdf[0] doc.png", $retval);
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
=> Last line of the output:
=> Return value: 5
```

I thought maybe the program wasn't lunched but...I can see it in the task manager and the CPU is working for some seconds, Imagick is doing something but in the end I haven't any kind of output!!! >_< I found a lot of topic about that but I haven't found a working solution...

Comment: I fancy _launching lunch_! Though it's more dinner time here in the UK... Anyway Ryuzaki, @Cal has a good suggestion - try his idea. Also, see [this recent post of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10056329/472495) in which I describe how to supply environment variables to a system command - maybe you need a `PATH` or `HOME` var set for `convert` to work?

Comment: oh, come on Marc C...I just forgot an "a" =.= try to be more helpful...

Comment: halfer, I "solved" putting Imagick executables (bin folder) inside "/opt/local/bin", libraries (lib folder) inside "/ImageMagick-6.7.5/lib" and modifying the "envvars" file in export PATH="$PATH:/opt/local/bin" (other lines are commented)

Comment: NOW I have no errors with "convert logo: logo.jpg" but I have problems with PDF conversion...but for today is enough =P next days I try again...I think is another path problem but now with GhostScript =.=

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping commands like this:

```
exec($cmd." 2>&1", $out, $ret);
if ($ret){
    echo "There was a problem!\n";
    print_r($out);
}else{
    echo "Everything went better than expected!\n";
}
```

`exec()` lets you capture all output and get the exit code. Adding `2>&1` makes sure to redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT` so you can see any error messages.

Comment: Great!!! I can finally read something =D


This is the error if I write "$cmd = MAGICK_PATH.'convert -version';"


There was a problem! Array ( [0] => dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart [1] => Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib [2] => Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libJPEG.dylib [3] => in /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libTIFF.dylib )

Comment: @Ryuzaki - my comment on the question itself may fix that. I suspect it needs environment variables (PATH, HOME, etc) to find stuff it needs.

Comment: what can I try to do? I don't know a lot about this things =\

Answer (score 0):

Also, as an addendum to my earlier comment: try supplying fully-qualified paths to your input and output filenames. Commands are launched in PHP with a default current working directory - and this may not be the same dir that the script is actually contained within.

If you want to see what your default directory is for system commands, try:

```
exec('pwd');
```

If any of your paths have spaces in (or if at any stage they contain user input) you should run your parameters through `escapeshellarg()` to make sure they will work (and that they are safe to run).

Comment: thank you, this was another thing I wanted to check! :) The result is right:


Everything went better than expected!
Array ( [0] => /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MIX/PDF )