# Lame encoder command in php shell_exec doesn't work via http server

Tags: php, shell-exec, lame

I have a problem with running lame encoder via shell_exec script in php.

And the broke my problem to just this script and noticed that the script works if I run it via php command in terminal, but doesn't work if I open it in a browser.
I have permissios of all files set to 777 just in case.

here's the code

```
< ?php

exec('lame -f -V 9 ../furniture/sound/107887.wav ../furniture/sound/107887.ogg');
```

The thing is that script works if I run it in terminal with php command, but doesn't via browser.

Oh and this scirpt takes really max two seconds, so it coundn't be a timeout or anything. I also get no php or nginx errors.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `exec` is probably disabled when running PHP through nginx.  Can't remember off the top of my head how to enable it (and in general it's a security hole which is why it should be disabled).  Should at least give you something to google...

Comment: does the command return any errors?

Comment: No, the thing is that in the initial script I run several shell_exec commands that seem to work great. The script the stopps with this one

Comment: The exec comnand returns an empty string

Comment: I'd try using full paths to start off with - PHP doesn't necessary run with the current working directory being the same as the directory the script is stored in. Also, it may be [your environment variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967217/inkscape-inside-php-apache-doesnt-render-fonts-to-png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is lame on php's execution `PATH`? Try replacing `lame` with `/usr/bin/lame` or whatever.

How about the relative pathnames to the file arguments? Is `../furniture/` etc. correct from the current directory as seen by PHP? If in doubt, replace these with full pathnames too and see if that fixes the problem.

Less likely but worth mentioning: You might want to check that `lame` itself has all its executable bits set. If you own the file and it's only executable by the owner, apache won't be able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reasons why it is not working from the webserver, perhaps resource or permission related. You can find this out by using the second optional parameter of exec:

```
<?php
$output = "";
exec('lame -f -V 9 ../furniture/sound/107887.wav ../furniture/sound/107887.ogg',$output);
echo $output;
?>
```