# Running wkhtmltopdf from PHP on OSX Lion results in error

Tags: php, pdf

I am getting this error, and I don't know if there's a way to update libiconv.2.dylib to version 8.0.0 ?

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
Reason: Incompatible library version: libxml2.2.dylib requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

Comment: Are you getting this error from the downloaded binary, or the one you build from source?

Comment: It's from the downloaded Library. As far as I understand the problem occurs because when I'm running from command line, i'm using my mac's built-in server, when i'm running from PHP, i'm using MAMP's server and there seem to be some libraries missing or mismatching...

Comment: Ah right, so the downloaded version of `wkhtmltopdf` works OK from the command line? Also: did you build the source version successfully? What happens if you run that from the command line? What happens if you run that from PHP?

Comment: Yes, the downloaded version works OK from command line. No, I did not build a version from source as I know that the latest version has bugs that the 0.10.0 rc2 does not have

Comment: But you explicitly state in your question that you "have tried building it from source"? If this is wrong, please update your question text. (I have an idea what might be wrong, will add it as an answer).

Comment: Hey, yes I tried building from source, but that version did not even work from CLI :) Anyway, I have resolved this by dumping MAMP and using the built-in PHP and Apache in OSX

Answer (score 0):

I have a theory that if you are running a binary and it works fine from the CLI but not from PHP, then you need to set your environment variables correctly. In general, commands are mostly sensitive to differences in `PATH` and `HOME`, which are set very minimally inside a PHP system call. Try copying these from your command line to your PHP env by using the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967217/inkscape-inside-php-apache-doesnt-render-fonts-to-png).