# Call osascript through php shell_exec doesn't work

Tags: php, shell-exec, osascript

I was trying some things with osascript when I had this problem.

Here is my test :

```
/usr/bin/osascript <<-EOF

    tell application "System Events"
        activate
        display dialog "Hello world"
    end tell

EOF
```

Here is my PHP file.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("./test");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Do you have any ideas why this does not work? (It's not really important but I was just curious about it)

Comment: Erm, so don't keep us in suspense! What output _do_ you get?

Comment: Try `shell_exec("/path/to/test 2>&1")` to redirect error output to stdout. Also, to be on the safe side, swap to a full path as illustrated.

Comment: `46:54: execution error: An error of type -10810 has occurred. (-10810)`

Comment: Aha! So, does this file execute correctly if you run it from the console?

Comment: ./test executes without problems. It's the first thing I tried !

Comment: See my answer, but also: do a web search for that error message to see if someone else has experienced it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the osascript executable requires environment variables to be set up to work correctly, which is why this works fine from the console. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10056329/472495) to show you how to set these up from PHP.

In my case it was the `HOME` variable, but it could be something else. Keep adding them until it works!

Comment: Well. It seems like error 10810 is because I asked the system to open the popup but the system doesn't want unless you do it from an app. I can call scripts directely with `system()` or `shell_exec()` that do not require GUI elements

Comment: Righto. Yes, I wouldn't expect anything that pops up dialogue boxes to work through PHP in a web process.