# php shell_exec("java -version") returning null

Tags: java, php, linux

I'm using the command:

```
shell_exec("java -version");
```

to detect what Java version is installed.   Java IS installed. The PHP script runs under the user "daemon".  Running this command from the command line:

```
su daemon -c 'java -version'
```

outputs

```
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.1) (6b27-1.12.1-2ubuntu0.12.04.2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I know using shell_exec works with Java and PHP because elsewhere in the code I'm running java .jar files using it.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Most likely the process running the php script does have a different `PATH` defined. That variable is typically defined in a shell startup script, that might make a difference. Have a try to address the java executable using an absolute path.

Comment: You can find the absolute path from the command line by typing `which java`.

Comment: Yeah, I agree the path is the likely culprit. Also, consider other environment variables, such as HOME - I've previously [encountered that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967217/inkscape-inside-php-apache-doesnt-render-fonts-to-png).

Comment: I would argue, as per my answer below, that PATH and other environment variables are not the issue due to the shell behavior using backticks, which exec_shell emulates.

Comment: @arkascha -  But elsewhere in the code I'm running "java file.jar" and it runs the file.jar just fine.  Also, I compared the "which java" from the command line as root, and from a print statement in the code, and they are the same: /usr/bin/java

Answer (score 3):

Add `2>&1` to the end of your shell command to have `STDERR` returned as well as `STDOUT`.

```
$output = shell_exec("java -version 2>&1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - `exec('java -version', $output);`

It's exec() not shell_exec()

[More detail here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Comment: exec('java -version', $output) returns an empty array

Comment: Have you tried this too? 
<?php
echo exec('java -version');
?>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Java is sending the output to stdout directly. If you run the command with backticks on the command line (as the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) says the command is equivalent to),  and try to store it in a variable, you'll see it gets printed out, but not stored in the variable.

For example:

```
foo=`java -version`
print $foo // results in nothing
```

However:

```
foo=`ls`
print $foo // results in the results of ls
```

You might try using [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) with the output variable instead.