# Why PHP exec() won't work in Windows 8 when it worked in Windows 7?

Tags: php, windows-8, exec

The following worked fine locally on Windows 7, but now the website is on Windows 8 and does not work. This is run in an Apache web request:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i "C:\temp\testing.mp4" "C:\temp\testing.mp3"', $errors, $result);
    var_dump($errors);
    var_dump($result);
    exit;
```

gives: `array(0) { } int(1)`

```
$output = exec('ffmpeg -i "C:\\temp\\testing.mp4" "C:\\temp\\testing.mp3"', $errors, $result);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($errors);
var_dump($result);
exit;
```

gives: `string(0) "" array(0) { } int(1)`

but if I execute the text `C:\temp\testing.mp4" "C:\temp\testing.mp3` in the command window in any directory (PATH is set to ffmpeg), it works fine.

I set the rights on `c:\temp` for all users to full control, but the MP3 file is still not created. Why is this statement not being executed in Windows 8 but is executed in Windows 7? How can I find out more information about why it is not creating the MP3 file?

Interestingly, this works:

```
exec('copy "C:\\temp\\testing.mp4" "C:\\temp\\testing.mp3"', $result);
var_dump($result);
```

and yields:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(30) " 1 file(s) copied." }
```

Comment: It might be the env vars are not being sent, and perhaps this command needs them. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10056329/472495) for ideas - that was on Mac, but it could apply to all OSes.

Comment: Also, are you running this command on the console or in the web server? If the latter, try the former, using `php test.php`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

After editing the Environment Path variable, **Restart Apache** for it to take effect in PHP.

Comment: Hmm, if were are running the PHP script from `cmd`, how could Apache have an effect on it? `:)`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I meant that I (1) was executing the PHP script via Apache where it wouldn't work, and then (2) was copying and pasting the command into the command prompt where it would work.

Comment: Ah righto. The intermediate thing to try would have been to see if the PHP `exec` worked at the console.